# Create modal popup window android(over all other window)

Tags: android

I'm using service and I want to create popup window over all other window, user can't choose other app before close my popup. How to do that?

Comment: Block people in your app until they do an action? Android doesn't work that way. Services are meant to start an activity or send an `Intent`. Not to mention that would be very intrusive.

Comment: I use service only to create popup.My popup as  same popup of GO SMS when receive new messega.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, not without a custom ROM.  That kind of behavior is considered malware.  You can only make a dialog window modal to your application, not to all apps.  Using the navigation buttons to go to the home screen or another app will always work.